# jQuery mobile list dividers - span to group li's that arn't a divider

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im using the jQuery Mobile list with dividers:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-divider.html

Currently the structure is like this (A and B are dividers):

```
<li>A</li>
<li>Adam</li>
<li>Alex</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>Bob</li>
<li>Barbara</li>
```

How can I put a span around li's that arnt dividers like so?:

```
<li>A</li>
  <span class="myspan">
    <li>Adam</li>
    <li>Alex</li>
  </span>
<li>B</li>
  <span class="myspan">
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>Barbara</li>
  </span>
```

I could run some javascript on page load that added these spans, but this seems a bit messy to me. Are there any practical downsides to doing this?  Thanks

UPDATE - The reason I want a span is I need it so when you click on a header, the li's below it collapse a bit like an accordion: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve?

Rather than using list divider, would it make sense to break your display into seperate listviews, i.e.

```
<h3>A</h3>
  <ul data-role="listview" >
    <li>Adam</li>
    <li>Alex</li>
  </ul>
<h3>B</h3>
  <ul data-role="listview" >
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>Barbara</li>
</ul>
```

This way you are not breaking the list's HTML.

*Edit* Another approach would be to just add classes to individual list items to visually indicate that they are grouped together. For example:

```
<ul data-role="listview" >
     <li class="group-a">Adam</li>
     <li class="group-a">Alex</li>
     <li class="group-b">Bob</li>
     <li class="group-b">Barbara</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I need one search field for my entire list. I also need it so clicking a header collapses and expands the list items in its section. Does it really break the html if I add a span rather than a div?

Comment: I don't know if adding a `span` would break the official HTML spec, have never seen it done though. Another consideration might be to style list items that should be in the same group by adding the same CSS class to them, so visually they look similar. This would allow you to still use the same search field for everything.

Comment: Ok, adding a class is probably a better. How can I do this? There are no classes to differentiate them by default. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the flip flop. I just realised I do actually need a span. Rather than just hiding all the items I want them to slide up, so they must be contained in a span or div. Thanks